What is Anderson saying?
I read the following on the internet:

According to Anderson, a long recognized feature of the Theravada
canon is that it lacks an "overarching and comprehensive structure of
the path to nibbana." The sutras form a network or matrix, which have
to be taken together.

What is this suppposed to mean?


According to Anderson, a long recognized feature of the Theravada canon is that it lacks an "overarching and comprehensive structure of the path to nibbana."
Wikipedia-Dhammacakkappavattana Sutta

No. As my understanding, Theravada canon contains fully detailed path to the nibbana / Nirvana.
One may say things like above, if he/she didn't learn the full context or if he/she seek complete(100%) world view through Damma.
(full context isn't required to reach Nirvana, though it may help to some people and it would be a barrier for some people (because they try to explain all the scenarios in the world through this world view.)).

There's 4 nobel truths.

There's 8 fold path.

There's Abidamma covering all the aspects of mind, matter, thoughts, nature of the universe.

There's Samatha meditation.

There's Vipassana meditation.

ect.....


What more do one want to reach Nirvana.
Above list is more than enough for one to reach Nirvana.
In the past when Buddha teach the Damma to people, Buddha didn't teach them, all the Damma, (like Buddha didn't teach people all the parts from above list) But only small part was thought. And this part(small piece of Damma) was enough for those individuals to reach Nirvana.
So one saying Damma is not enough, Damma is not complete is not true, and shows lack of enough education about Damma or lack of intellect to understand Damma.

The sutras form a network or matrix, which have to be taken together.

Yes. Damma books look like a network or matrix.
Why this network or matrix exist?
It's because,

Buddha taught Damma at specific situations for specific people, to suit their personality, thinking.

Later attempt to write down the Damma. At this writing down, there wasn't anyone like Buddha or Sariputta, that can actually comprehend the all Damma and rearrange or create more sophisticated system. They (Sanga at writing down) wanted to just preserve Damma as is(as they had it). Without changing.


Yet, All the Damma is not required to reach Nirvana. Only to construct a full world view or full map of Damma. Which isn't required for reaching the Nirvana.(which may look cool, useful and easy to comprehend, if is constructed.)
I mean, what network? What matrix?
Is he talking about Samsara or physical reality?
If so,
There are like vast amount of detailed explanations about Samsara and physical reality in Damma. Maybe he didn't learn them or couldn't find them in Damma.


Learning / memorising the process / path to Nirvana is one thing and understanding / experiencing is one thing.
Learning / memorising the process / path to Nirvana wouldn't guarantee the understanding it, though it would help to understand.

But why ? , one may ask.
Why is

Learning / memorising the process / path to Nirvana is one thing and understanding / experiencing is one thing.

?
It's like this, imagine someone heard about a new cake recipe(actual cake that can eat). Which said to be very testy like never experienced before.
Now, one can read the recipe, memorise it, write it in books, read again, follow step-by-step in the mind, teach it to others, imagine making the cake, imagine the sense of sweatiness of the cake, imagine the taste of the cake, imagine eating the cake, like he/she can do this all his/her life.
But would he/she feel the actual taste?
Or
would he/she feel, what would feel if he/she actually eat the cake?
No. Right?
One should follow the recipe and make the cake themselves and eat it to feel the actual taste.
That's why.

Mostly, people who say Damma is incomplete are people who seek complete(100%) world view from Buddhism(but not people who seek Nirvana) . They try to get explanation from Buddhism for every scenario imaginable, every experience they had, every experience others had, every story they heard. Which is infinite scenarios if they can comprehend them all.
Which in turn would take infinite comprehensive power, infinite time, infinite resources. Which is exact Parable of the Poisoned Arrow.
One who seek freedom from Dukka and seek Nirvana shouldn't do that. (it's okay to do that at the beginning, until enough trust build up on Damma) But one who seek Nirvana should focus his/her resources on following the path.
Thanks . ☸️.
Questions are welcome.

Your saying "learn the full context", with a list that includes the abidhamma, sounds to me like the same as the quote "a network or matrix which have to be taken together" -- so I don't see why you start the answer with "No", instead the answer seems more like an agreement. Maybe where you disagree is, is at the end of the answer where you may be saying that "any small piece from the Dhamma may be enough", for some people i.e. for "those individuals".

Okay. I updated my answer.  Your saying "learn the full context", with a list that includes the abidhamma, sounds to me like the same as the quote "a network or matrix which have to be taken together" isn't required to reach Nirvana. But a complete world view. (which is not understanding but memorising causes and effects, scenarios, all the variables).

I actually dont think you understand the quote correctly. These network of matrixes is like having to learn SN4.7 and MN3.83, then DN.2.46 to get the idea and learn of a concept. The numbers themselves being an example but that is the "network and matrixes" he is stating. There is no comprehensive structure as he is stating. Not until later sangha created a structural system encompassing Buddhas teachings.

Yes. I read your answer(and up voted). It's true matrix exists. I was reading the quote without the context. But later I found the full context. But knowing all the matrix isn't required to reach Nirvana. That's my point. Each little piece of Damma contains full Damma.


overarching and comprehensive structure of the path to nibbana

He is obviously correct though isn't he.
When after Buddhas death the original sangha that was left devised a method to mentally retain the teachings so they can be given to others orally they formed it in such a way that I assume was more important to be repetitive to be able to be learned by others than comprehensive in structure. Hence why when there came to the point when later sangha were able to write it down there is constant repetition in the EBT doctrines. That as well as that not everyone had access to books so the teachings would have been held by the sangha and repeated as if a chant, or a song for others to learn.
Now that is just logic, but the way the Theravada nikayas are structured are clearly rather nonsensical from a study orientated perspective.
The way they are written down is in shortest to largest numbers of written lines or discourse. Like SN.1 is SN book 1 (1 line) and SN.10 book of 10s (10 lines) Which doesn't even equate correctly when you translate the teachings to other languages as a SN 2 line teachings could be 3 lines of words in arabic and visa versa for an SN 3 line...using an example of course.
Another example, the 1st teachings Buddha gave was the 4 noble truths, the 1st turning of the wheel of dharma, this is in the DN (longest discourses), but the next teaching he gave was the 8fold path, the suttas for explanations of all the 8 are in MN (iirc). Meaning you would have to change an entire "book" to even learn the Buddhas teachings in chronological order of being taught, let alone systematically to make "sense"
This is why later the sangha created their own unique systematic studies, specifically the abhidhamma and the visuddhimagga. To make the actual path to liberation a rather systematic point A-Z progress. As learning the Buddhas teachings via starting with and ending with any of the nikayas are going to give us a rather disjointed perception of the entire path of what actually needs to be done.
This is of course my own understanding.

Thanks. Most preaching the abhidhamma and the visuddhimagga have not actually read these books that in essence infer the Buddha was an imperfect & incomplete teacher. The Triple Refuge includes "svakhato bhavagata dhammo", which means "the dhamma perfectly explained by the Buddha". Thank you again for your effort

I myself have not studied these books yet either, but I do know that they are an attempt by the sangha to create a structure to the teachings where the nikayas are as I stated ordered in length of teaching rather than in a systematic understanding of what to practice.

I have studied them and they are not related to the suttas

What is this supposed to mean?
Maybe a lot of doctrines have no "centre" -- what's the centre of "mathematics" for example? A student might seize on some lesson and say, "this was most important", but there's more.
More importantly ;-) what about the fact that the Three Trainings are also a Gradual Training? Which I think means that only Sila is taught to laypeople, maybe even only Dana? In which case most what we might think of as "core" doctrine is untaught (see also e.g. this comment).
Maybe it's like medicine? A doctor's knowledge is in-depth and broad and takes many years to learn. Sometimes they use one part of that knowledge, sometimes another -- it depends on the situation i.e. what the problem is.
